# LiveServer going to offline in chrome developer-tools responsive section

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-code, google-chrome-devtools, liveserver

i was using happily liveserver in vs-code for a long time , but there are few days when i run my html document with live server in chrome and go to the chrome responsive section in developer tools
live server going to offline
please help me

*thanks =)*

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfRmr.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.